# Apache Tomcat will close connection on file download with non blocking http protocol

Tags: java, tomcat

Per default the protocol in server.xml is configured as **protocol="HTTP/1.1"**.
with newer tomcat versions this will use a non blocking protocol if possible.

Problem:
Setup Tomcat (8.0.28) with default settings.
Copy a file in a webapp e.g. webapps/root and download the file with limited speed to simulate a slow modem download.

```
wget http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/xxxxxxx/7.zip --limit-rate=1k
```

Connection will be closed always after 6minutes and 24seconds

```
Saving to: ‘7.zip’
7.zip               0%[                      ] 767.99K  1.00KB/s   in 6m 24s
2015-10-28 17:27:39 (1024 B/s) - Connection closed at byte 786426. Retrying.
```

if i change the protocol to (blocking):

```
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
```

everything is fine and the download will complete with slow speed.

What could be the issue?

Comment: After some more investigation it has sth to do with the speed. if i change it to 10kb/sec it seems working. if i use 5kb/sec it will always stop after exactly 77sec or 102sec. i still dont see any pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known limitiation with the new apache protocols.

The only solution to have a stable connection below 64kb/sec is to change the settings:
socket.txBufSize (smaller)
and connection timeout (higher).
for more details check:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58565