# Writing large content to servlet response fails

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I have a simple servlet (running in Tomcat8), that can be abbreviated as follows:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    byte[] b = "some very large content\n".getBytes()
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        out.write(b);
    }
}
```

I'm using Apache HTTPClient to consume this, essentially like this:

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = ...;
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

For small sized of data it works fine, but if it the data get's beyond a certain size it the client does not consume the response. Seems like nothing is being sent?

Important to note that I do not know the size of the data in advance so cannot specify the Content-Length header.

What is the right approach for sending large responses on unknown size?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry could not comment!

One reason could be read-write connection timeout. Tomcat closes a connection when the read/write operation is getting lengthy. ([ref](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation)). ([seme issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397442/apache-tomcat-will-close-connection-on-file-download-with-non-blocking-http-prot))

You may try set the connection timeout to -1(no timeout) and try again, but this is not good if you are working BIO (either connection, or backend ops).